# PerformSearch Method in Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport

Tags: vb.net, winforms, reporting-services, microsoft-reporting

Can someone explain about PerformSearch Method in Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport

```
ServerReport As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport = Nothing

int result=ServerReport.GetType.GetMethod("PerformSearch", Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(ServerReport, {SearchValue, CurrentPage + 1, CurrentPage + 1})
```

What are the input parameters and return value for PerformSearch method?

Comment: Where is the documentation for this method?  You can't write reflection code against a method if you don't know what the exact method signature is, and the only way to get that is to consult the documentation.

Comment: [The documentation for the ServerReport class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.serverreport.aspx) says that the method you're trying to call doesn't exist.  Nor does it exist on the [base class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.report.aspx).

Comment: Type Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ServerReport.GetType , you can able to see PerformSearch method under DeclaredMethods. I can't find any documentation for this methods anywhere in web.

Comment: If you don't have any documentation for this method, then how do you know what it does?

Comment: Where do I get the assembly that contains the `Microsoft.Reporting.Winforms` namespace?

Comment: This snippet was present in some old code and this method is returning some integer values. I want to know about this method.

Comment: we can get it from nuget

Comment: Yeah, finally found it on nuget.  One moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I loaded up [this Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.v11/), fired up [Telerik JustDecompile](https://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx), opened `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll`, did a search on `PerformSearch`, and found the method.  This is what the method looks like:

```
    internal override int PerformSearch(string searchText, int startPage, int endPage)
    {
        int num;
        lock (this.m_syncObject)
        {
            if (!this.IsReadyForProcessingPostTasks)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(CommonStrings.ReportNotReady);
            }
            num = this.Service.FindString(startPage, endPage, searchText);
        }
        return num;
    }
```

If you want to find out more, you can download and install JustDecompile yourself.  The `FindString()` method in the code above is clickable in JustDecompile; it will take you to that method in the source.

Comment: Thank you very much @Robert Harvey